# Delphi and enum

Tags: delphi

Does Delphi have an analog of enum in C?

Comment: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Sets

Comment: I don't know why everyone is linking to the DelphiBasics.co.uk site's article on enumerations, when the official documentation is available. Always prefer the official documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Enumerated_Types

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I think this is because the official documentation was not accessible at the time.

Comment: As a general note: Delphi always had better support for types, then C.

Answer (score 46):

Yes, Delphi has the following enumerated type construction:

```
type
  TDigits = (dgOne, dgTwo, dgThree <etc>);
```

Also, like in C, each symbol of an enumerated type may have
a specified value, like this:

```
type
  TDigits = (dgOne = 1, dgTwo, dgThree <etc>);
```

Comment: It should be added that the constants automatically get incremented (in relation to the direct predecessor) if there's no explicit value specified.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Check out the first portion of [Delphi Basics: Enumerations, SubRanges, and Sets.](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Sets)

Comment: I don't know why everyone is linking to the DelphiBasics.co.uk site's article on enumerations, when the official documentation is available. Always prefer the official documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Enumerated_Types

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at

[Enumerations, SubRanges and Sets](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Sets)

Comment: I don't know why everyone is linking to the DelphiBasics.co.uk site's article on enumerations, when the official documentation is available. Always prefer the official documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Enumerated_Types

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the positive responses that are focused on the parallels, there are

### Some restrictions:

#### 1. Anonymous enumerations are not supported in Delphi.

So you have to translate

```c
enum { SOME_CONSTANT = 42 };
```

into

```pascal
const
  SOME_CONSTANT = 42
```

… which is, by the way, a better wording for your actual intent. But unfortunately, this can be translated back into something different. At least C++Builder 6 translates it like this in the auto-generated `*.hpp` file:

```cpp
static const Shortint SOME_CONSTANT = 0x2A;
```

#### 2. Explicit enum values were added with Delphi 6.

The feature of explicitly adding values to enumerators was introduced with [Delphi 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460108/2932052). So you have to switch to normal constants, see [this answer to *How to create an enum with explicit values in Delphi 5*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68712194/2932052) for more.

#### 3. Finally, a restriction of C:

In C, enumerations are just compile-time constants that are implicitly converted into `int` as needed. This is basically where the support ends. Delphi has a stronger typing but provides information about the valid range and also iteration, see this snippet:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TMyEnum = (meOne, meTwo, meThree);
var
  v: TMyEnum;
  txt: String;
begin
  for v := Low(TMyEnum) to High(TMyEnum) do
    txt := txt + IntToStr(Integer(v)) + ' ';
  ShowMessage(txt)
end;
```