# How to create an enum with explicit values in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, enums

Currently I am recompiling a higher version of Delphi (XE) project to lower version 5.

I have multiple enums with explicit values as below:

```
type 
  TSize = (ftSmallSize=10, ftMediumSize=15, ftLargeSize=20, ftExtralarge=24)
```

When I compile this code, an error occurs with the message:

> ',' or ')' expected but '=' found

How can I recompile this code in Delphi 5?

Comment: I tried this in Delphi 4, and indeed it is considered a syntax error. A workaround is this: `type TSize = Byte; const ftSmallSize = 10; ftMediumSize = 15; ftExtraLarge = 24;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the option to specify fixed (ordinal) values in an enumeration [was added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460108/282848) in Delphi 6.

Probably the simplest workaround is to do

```pascal
type
  TSize = Byte;

const
  ftSmallSize = 10;
  ftMediumSize = 15;
  ftExtraLarge = 24;
```

Obviously, you lose some type safety, but it will (likely) compile without any further changes.

Just make sure to choose an integer type of the right size when you define `TSize`. You should make it the same as `SizeOf(TSize)` in your original code.

Comment: Trivia: I never even tried to declare enum types with fixed values but instead declared constants right away in D7. Good to know I can.

Comment: That this feature, that specific values can be added to enumerators, was added in Delphi 6 is the exact information I was searching for, hard to google but `',' or ')' expected but '=' found [delphi]` on SO did it.

Answer (score 3):

You can decouple the values from the enum type:

```
type
  TSize = (ftSmallSize, ftMediumSize, ftLargeSize, ftExtralarge);
const
  cSizeValues: array[TSize] of Integer = (10, 15, 20, 24);
```

Or define a function `GetSizeValue(ASize: TSize)` with a `case ASize of` - that would be more flexible.

Use like it this:

```
 Edit1.Height := cSizeValues[ftMediumSize];
```

or

```
 Edit1.Height := GetSizeValue(ftMediumSize);
```

Comment: In general, you also need a function that performs a simple linear search for the inverse transformation. (And of course, with this solution you still have full type safety, but a lot of code may require tiny adjustments: `ftMediumSize -> cSizeValues[ftMediumSize]`.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: You're right, for existing code to downgrade it's probably not worth the hassle. For new types I'd prefer it over enum types with explicit values as well as constants.

Comment: If access is a general standard call, then one can consider overriding the operators.
[http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Operator_Overloading]